# Add shade gradient to the bottom of a uitableviewcell / uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, gradient

Does anyone know how add a gradient to the bottom of a uitableviewcell or the uiimageview like the image shown below does?

[image]

Comment: Create a CAGradientLayer with transparent and transluscent region. Then set cell's contentView's layer's mask to this gradient layer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this class into your project (**swift**):

```
class UIGradientImageView: UIImageView {

let myGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer

 override init?(frame: CGRect){
    myGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
    addGradientLayer()
 }

 func addGradientLayer(){
    if myGradientLayer.superlayer == nil{
        self.layer.addSublayer(myGradientLayer)
    }
 }

 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    myGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
    addGradientLayer()
 }

 func getColors() -> [CGColorRef] {
    return [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor]
 }

 func getLocations() -> [CGFloat]{
    return [0.5,  0.9]
 }

 func setup() {
     myGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
     myGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    
     let colors = getColors()
     myGradientLayer.colors = colors
     myGradientLayer.opaque = false
     myGradientLayer.locations = getLocations()
 }

 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    myGradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
 }
}
```

**UPDATE: Objective-C translated solution. Credits to @SleepsOnNewspapers.**

```
 #import "UIGradientImageView.h"

 @interface UIGradientImageView()

  @property (nonatomic, strong) CAGradientLayer *myGradientLayer;

 @end

 @implementation UIGradientImageView

 -(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

 if(self){
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  self.myGradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc]init];
  [self setup];
  [self addGradientLayer];
  }
 return self;
 }

 -(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

 if(self){
   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   self.myGradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc]init];
   [self setup];
   [self addGradientLayer];
  }
  return self;
 }

 -(void)addGradientLayer{
 if (self.myGradientLayer.superlayer == nil) {
  [self.layer addSublayer:self.myGradientLayer];
 }
}
```

Make your `UIImageView` class on your storyboard to be this one instead of default.

[image]

Comment: any difference between this and CGGradientLayer? Also is the implementation of this much different in objective c?

Comment: ..should be similar. Just translate from swift to Objective-C, everything is available.

Comment: this code will not work. It does not take into account that uitableviewcells are redrawn

Comment: each time i scroll the gradient gets darker and darker. thoughts?

Comment: mm...yes, just make sure that your layer is already there, if it is, just not add another one. It is stacking. I will check my code and fix this if needed

Comment: Eitherway, check that `func addGradientLayer()` gets called only on init functions and that you have already checked that you did not miss any line. (are you translating into Objective-C?)

Comment: I made the mistake of not subclassing and instead putting this code in cellForRow:atIndexPath:

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers Hi!, I'm seeing that you assigned this as the correct answer and after you resigned that status, do you have a better approach?

Comment: although I get a warning on the clear color CGColorRef, the solution worked just fine for me after I correctly translated to Objective-C. @Hugo Alonso

Comment: probably was just a mistake I made. thanks for the answer, well deserved!

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers I added your solution as an update to this answer, I was considering adding it as another answer but on its base is the same answer, just that this one is translated to Objective-C, also, I will feel bad if were earning points for your solution :)